# I am getting the error cannot run adl error=13 permission denied

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using a CS Flex SDK 3.4.0 from Adobe and it is giving me the following error when I try to compile anything with it:

```
Cannot run program "/Users/me/Downloads/creativesuiteCS5_swc/cssdk-free/CreativeSuiteSDK/CS Flex SDK 3.4.0/bin/adl": error=13, Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to grant permissions to adl.

```
cd /Users/me/Downloads/creativesuiteCS5_swc/cssdk-free/CreativeSuiteSDK/CS\ Flex\ SDK\ 3.4.0/bin
chmod a+x ./*
```

I though I ran chmod a+x ./* and I was still getting the error, then it turned out I was not in the bin directory. I switched to that directory and ran it again and it is now compiling. Thanks everyone. You've all been great.